# WebStorm 2016 support for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, webstorm

Is it normal that WebStorm 2016 does not recognize *__dirname* or *__filename* as NodeJS special vars? By not recognizing I mean it does not give code hinting for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's there:

[image]

Please make sure that `Node.js Core` library is enabled in `Settings (Preferences) | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and NPM`